# Connect an execute insert query to another database of another server

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I am using SQL Server on a Windows Server.

The scenario is that i have the SQLInstance1 to the windows Server1 and the Instance2 to the Windows Server 2. The 2 Windows servers aren't in the same domain, but i know their IP.

I would like to know if i can run a stored procedure, from SQLInstance1, in order to insert some data to the SQLInstance2. Is it possible? If yes, can you tell me how?

Comment: for different servers, the easy and quick way is to use ETL toosl like SSIS

Comment: SSIS will have to connect to the server and execute the SP and if the SP do not have a linked server he can't insert data into other serveur. 

or he can execute the SP and get the result into a stagin table then insert into the other instance .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes it is possible to do this :

1 - even you use a Linked server and run the store precedure from instance1 to insert into instance2 , you have to create linked server and give acces ot the user that will run the SP on the other instance

here is how to use linked serveurs

click [here] (https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/sql/relational-databases/linked-servers/linked-servers-database-engine?view=sql-server-2017)!

Answer (score 1):

You can set up [Linked Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/linked-servers/create-linked-servers-sql-server-database-engine?view=sql-server-2017). Then you just need to call by their alias, almost the same like calling table from another database.